# Sorting IP Addresses using XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am trying to sort data from a CSV file that is parsed via PHP.  The PHP takes the data and turns it into XML, which is then formatted by an XSL stylesheet.  The data contains an IP address, a date, and user agent.  The XSL groups the data by IP address and I need it to sort by IP address as well.

Here is my XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="group-by-ipaddress" match="row" use="ipaddress" />
    <xsl:template match="rows">
        <html>
            <body>

                <xsl:for-each select="row[count(. | key('group-by-ipaddress', ipaddress)[1]) = 1]">
                        <xsl:sort select="ipaddress"/>

                            <p>IP Address: <xsl:value-of select="ipaddress"/></p>
                                <xsl:for-each select="key('group-by-ipaddress', ipaddress)">
                                    <xsl:sort select="date" />
                                <p><blockquote>Date: <xsl:value-of select="date"/> : <xsl:value-of select="userAgent"/></blockquote></p>

                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It groups everything great, but the sorting is not quite working.  The sort works up until the last IP address, which starts with 5.  That one should be the first one in the sort, but it is the last one for some reason.  This is the output I get:  Any suggestions?

IP Address: 12.22.333.44

```
Date: 2013-01-02 : http://www.zorro.com
```

IP Address: 123.33.44.55

```
Date: 2013-01-03 : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0

Date: 2013-01-03 : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

Date: 2013-01-06 : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

Date: 2013-01-07 : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

IP Address: 212.38.44.55

```
Date: 2013-01-02 : Mozilla/3.0 (x86 [en] Windows NT 5.1; Sun)

Date: 2013-01-06 : Mozilla/3.0 (x86 [en] Windows NT 5.1; Sun)
```

IP Address: 256.19.44.55

```
Date: 2013-01-06 : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
```

IP Address: 5.255.23.25

```
Date: 2013-02-02 : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)

Date: 2013-02-05 : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are alpha-sorting the IP addresses here, and `12.22.333.44` alphabetizes before `5.255.23.25`. If  you want to sort them properly, it's not going to be so pretty:

```
<xsl:for-each select="row[count(. | key('group-by-ipaddress', ipaddress)[1]) = 1]">
  <xsl:sort select="substring-before(ipaddress, '.')" 
            data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:sort select="substring-before(
                    substring-after(ipaddress, '.'), '.')" 
            data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:sort select="substring-before(
                    substring-after(
                    substring-after(ipaddress, '.'), '.'), '.')" 
            data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:sort select="substring-after(
                    substring-after(
                    substring-after(ipaddress, '.'), '.'), '.')" 
            data-type="number"/>

  <!-- Contents of for-each -->

</xsl:for-each>
```